# Problems with installing pywin32 (python 3.6, windows 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I have just recently downloaded pywin32, made sure that it is the correct version (python 3.6). When trying to install I get following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCXMi.png)

Shortly after, the installer crashes. Running the installer as an administrator, as suggested, does not change anything.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Did you try running the installer as an administrator?

Comment: Are you sure you ran as Administrator? (Right-clicked the application and chose *Run as Administrator* from the menu? And entered admin credentials if it prompted for them?)

Comment: Running as an administrator did not work for me. I went on to download ActivePython where pywin32 is preinstalled. Thank you for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I was not able to fix the problem per se, I just downloaded ActivePython 3.6 which came with the module pywin32 pre-installed.